# How to replace the puntuation marks in words with effective code?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have been working on a file which has lot of puntuations and we need to neglect the puntuations so we can count the actual length of words.

Example:

Is this stack overflow! ---> Is this stack overflow

While doing this I did wrote a lot of cases for each and every punctuation which is there which made my code work slow.So I was looking for some effective way to implement the same using a module or function.

Code snippet :

```
with open(file_name,'r') as f:
     for line in f:
         for word in line.split():
            #print word
            '''
                Handling Puntuations
            '''
            word = word.replace('.','')
            word = word.replace(',','')
            word = word.replace('!','')
            word = word.replace('(','')
            word = word.replace(')','')
            word = word.replace(':','')
            word = word.replace(';','')
            word = word.replace('/','')
            word = word.replace('[','')
            word = word.replace(']','')
            word = word.replace('-','')
```

So form this logic I have written this, so is there any way to minimize this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411771/multiple-character-replace-with-python

Comment: Look at the ACSII value of those punctuation characters they should be in the same range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is a "classic", but a lot of answers don't work in Python 3 because the `maketrans` function has been removed from Python 3. A Python 3-compliant solution is:

use `string.punctuation` to get the list and `str.translate` to remove them

```
import string
"hello, world !".translate({ord(k):"" for k in string.punctuation})
```

results in:

```
'hello world '
```

the argument of `translate` is (in Python 3) a dictionary. Key is the ASCII code of the character, and value is the replacement character. I created it using a dictionary comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression to replace from a character class as

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'[]!,:)([/-]', '', string)
'Is this stack overflow'
```

- `[]!,:)([/-]` A character class which matches `]` or `!` or `,` or etc. Replace it with `''`.