# How to replace the right letters in a string python

Tags: python

The assignment is:

Your task is correcting the errors in the digitized text. You only have to handle the following mistakes:

- S is misinterpreted as 5
- O is misinterpreted as 0
- I is misinterpreted as 1

My code:

```
def correct(string):
    for i in string:
        if '5' in string:
           string = string.replace('5','S') 
        elif '0' in string:
          string = string.replace('0','O')
        elif '1' in string:
            string = string.replace('1','I')
    return string
```

I know this solution will not work for a word like:

```
Test.assert_equals(correct("51NGAP0RE"),"SINGAPORE");
```

Does anyone have tips on how to make this a more general function that will work for every word?

Comment: Why do you have a for loop, and the `if in` checks? Just doing the replacements would work better.

Comment: On a small number of replacements, @internet_user is correct. See also [string.translate](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) for more flexibilty

Comment: This is task from CodeWars: https://www.codewars.com/kata/577bd026df78c19bca0002c0

Comment: Are you sure your code doesn't work? It's not as efficient as it could be, but it should still give the correct answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple character replace with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411771/multiple-character-replace-with-python)

Comment: Don't name your variable `string` as it conflicts with the `string` library- if you're using python2, it would make a difference for the solution given by chrisz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `elif`, since that only does a test if the previous one failed. Change them all to ordinary `if` and the code will work correctly.

But as mentioned in the comments, there's no need for any of the tests. If the letter isn't in the string, `replace()` will just return the original string, so there's no harm.

```
string = string.replace('5', 'S').replace('0', 'O').replace('1', 'I')
```

Comment: My initial thought too but OP is iterating over each character in the string, so the `elif`/`if` shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Good point. If the string is at least 3 characters long it should perform all the replacements.

Comment: And if it's shorter, it can't need all the replacements.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `str.replace` directly.

```
def correct(string):
    return string.replace('5','S').replace('0','O').replace('1','I')
```

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you make use of [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
>>> "51NGAP0RE".translate(str.maketrans('501', 'SOI'))
'SINGAPORE'
```

Wrapped in a function:

```
def correct(s):
    return s.translate(str.maketrans('501', 'SOI'))
```

Comment: In python2, this is in the [`string`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) library. A great reason not to use `string` as a variable name!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However it needs to work for every word :)

Comment: @DaphneCornelisse You did not understand the answer. This works for every word, not only 501. This is just the way the maketrans function works.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon my bad! I just meant that it had to be a function.

Comment: Well then just put that line into a function, it really isn't hard. Plus, this is the best way to go with the kind of problem you are trying to solve. `def correct(s): return s.translate(str.maketrans('501', 'SOI'))`

Answer (score 2):

Here's another method using list comprehension:

```
def correct(str_, replacements = {'5': 'S', '0': 'O', '1': 'I'}):
    return "".join(replacements.get(c, c) for c in str_)
print(correct("51NGAP0RE"))
#'SINGAPORE'
```