# A more efficient way to format strings sequentially?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am manipulating strings sequentially. However, it looks bulky and may also not be efficient in performance in code execution. Is there a better way to run this maybe in a function?

```
df=['Apple sauce','Banana & peach','c(&)a']

df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '')
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('&','') 
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('(','')
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(')','')

Desired Out: df=['applesauce','bananapeach','ca']
```

Comment: Remember that df.str.replace uses regular expressions by default, so you may just use a character group for the replacement. `df.columns.str.replace('[ &()]','') `

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh thank you so much! How would we incooperate the lower() command in your code?

Comment: You could simply do it in two steps: `df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()` and then `df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('[ &()]','')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you could use a regex to simultaneously replace several characters. Additionally, you could also *chain* the various replacements since both `lower` and `replace` return a copy of the object after the appropriate replacement(s):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower().str.replace('[ &()]', '')
```

or

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('[ &()]', '').str.lower()
```

Answer (score 1):

[Saswat Padhi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57862625/9302488)'s solution is very cool, but it's not very efficient. If your problem was efficiency, you can consider my solution(with regex) to be around 2 times faster. 
This is my code:

```
import re
columns = df.columns
skipped = '[ &()]'
formatted_columns = [re.sub(skipped, '', col).lower() for col in columns]
df.columns = formatted_columns
```

Here are the measurements:

#### 1. regex

```
%%timeit
columns = df.columns
formatted_columns = [re.sub(skipped, '', col).lower() for col in columns]
df.columns = formatted_columns
# 231 µs ± 56.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

#### 2. str.lower() and str.replace()

```
%%timeit
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('[ &()]', '').str.lower()
# 483 µs ± 112 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower().str.replace('[ &()]', '')
# 500 µs ± 71.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

You can find a beautiful answer [Replacing two characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27086669/9302488), where you can find many comparisons on execution times.