# How to remove punctuation in Python without leaving a space

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to remove certain punctuations from a text. I was able to remove my desired characters but it keep leaving a space instead of the character.

```
In { ) other news tonight,
a Constitutional { | / !! amendment
```

I have a text such as above and when I process it it becomes

```
In   other news tonight,
a Constitutional    !! amendment
```

Instead of

```
In other news tonight,
a Constitutional !! amendment
```

Below is the code I have

```
for line in lines:
    exclude = set('"#$%&\()*+-/:<=>@[\\]^_`{|}')
    line = ''.join(ch for ch in line if ch not in exclude)
```

How do I remove empty spaces that are being produced?

Comment: an aside: create the set outside your loop.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga right!

Comment: Benchmarks on multiple string replacements - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27086669/4180176

Answer (score 1):

No empty spaces are being created. Your string already has empty spaces between these characters. Removing those characters will not remove the spaces in between them. One potential solution is that I assume you want to remove any areas with more than one consecutive space. Replace your code with:

```
exclude = set('"#$%&\()*+-/:<=>@[\\]^_`{|}')
for line in lines:
    line = ''.join(ch for ch in line if ch not in exclude)
    line = ' '.join(line.split())
```

Which will remove all double spaces.

Comment: So one problem with that is that "18-year-old" becomes "18yearold". But I want it to bed "18 year old"

Comment: @JohnSean Then remove the dash from your excluded character and maybe make a new list which is characters to be replaced by spaces. Then in between the two joins add line = ' '.join(ch for ch in line if ch not in spacereplace)

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string with the `str.split` method so that multiple spaces are treated as one, and then join the resulting list back into a string by a space:

```
exclude = set('"#$%&\()*+-/:<=>@[\\]^_`{|}')
for line in lines:
    line = ' '.join(''.join(' ' if ch in exclude else ch for ch in line).split())
```

Comment: So one problem with that is that "18-year-old" becomes "18yearold". But I want it to bed "18 year old"

Comment: Oops. Fixed then.

Comment: I got ```1 8 y e a r o l d L o o k , W i l l , w e ' r e a l m o s t t h e r e .```

Comment: Oops. Fixed again.