# Replace multiple chars in one run

Tags: python

I want to have a program like the one below:

```
a = xy
b = a.replace("x", "y")
c = b.replace("y", "x")
print(c)
```

And I want the output to be "yx" but because the program is running the same string again the output is looking like "xx".

I hope you're getting my point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to replace multiple characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411771/best-way-to-replace-multiple-characters-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `str.replace`, you can make a translation table - which is really just a dict mapping the ordinal values:

```
>>> string = "hello world"
>>> translation_table = str.maketrans("el", "le")
>>> translation_table
{101: 108, 108: 101}
>>> string.translate(translation_table)
'hleeo wored'
>>>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411771/best-way-to-replace-multiple-characters-in-a-string

Answer (score 0):

You have xy

you replace the x by y sou you have yy

Then you replace y by x so you get xx

You ca do:

```
A="xy"
B=a.replace("x","z")
C=B.replace("y","x")
D=C.replace("z","y")
print(D)
#yx
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question but maybe this could work:

```
a = 'xy'
letters = [char for char in a]
b = ''
for l in reversed(letters):
    b += l
print(b)
```

And the final outcome is`yx`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your exemple:

```
c=a.replace("xy","yx")
```

Or for more general solution, if you are not looking for high time performance on big data volume, you can iterate:

```
c=[] 
for i in range(0,len(a)-1,1):
    if a[i]=="x":
        c[i] ="y"
    elif  a[i]=="y" :
        c[i] ="x"
    else:
         c[i] =a[i]
```