# .replace only replaces last character in list

Tags: python, string, replace

```
title = 'Example#@@@+||'

blacklisted_chars = ['#','|','@','+']

for i in blacklisted_chars:
    convert = title.replace(i, '')
    
print(convert)

# Example#@@@||
```

I want to remove all blacklisted characters in a list and replace them with '', however when the code is run only the final 'blacklisted_char' is replaced within the print statement

I am wondering how I would make it that all characters are replaced and only 'Example' is printed

Comment: In the loop, you are saving the result as `convert`.  Each loop, you are _replacing_ the value of `convert`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to replace multiple characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411771/best-way-to-replace-multiple-characters-in-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable in python. You assign a *new* string with

```
convert = title.replace(i, '')
```

`title` remains unchanged after this statement. `convert` is an entirely new string that is missing `i`.

On the next iteration, you replace a different value of `i`, but still from the original `title`. So in the end it looks like you only ran

```
convert = title.replace('+', '')
```

You have two very similar options, depending on whether you want to keep the original `title` around or not.

If you do, make another reference to it, and keep updating that reference with the results, so that each successive iteration builds on the result of the previous removal:

```
convert = title
for i in blacklisted_chars:
    convert = convert.replace(i, '')
    
print(convert)
```

If you don't care to retain the original `title`, use that name directly:

```
for i in blacklisted_chars:
    title = title.replace(i, '')
    
print(title)
```

You can achieve a similar result without an explicit loop using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
convert = re.sub('[#|@+]', '', title)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
title = 'Example#@@@+||'

blacklisted_chars = ['#','|','@','+']

for i in blacklisted_chars:
    title = title.replace(i, '')
    
print(title)
```

Explanation: Since you were storing the result of `title.replace` in the `convert` variable, every iteration it was being overwritten. What you need is to apply `replace` to the result of the previous iteration, which can be the variable with the original string or another variable containing a copy of it if you want to keep the original value unchanged.

P.S.: strings are iterables so you can also achieve the same results with something like this:

```
blacklisted_chars = '#|@+'
```

Comment: Nice job with the update. It's much better when you explain what's happening.