# How remove multiple characters from multiple txt files

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a script to automate a simple task of removing characters from txt files and I want to save it with the same name but without the chars. I have multiple txt files: e.g 1.txt, 2.txt ... 200.txt, stored in a directory (Documents). I have a txt file with the characters I want to remove. At the beginning I though to compare my chars_to_remove.txt to all my different files (1.txt, 2.txt...) but I could find a way to do so. Instead, I created a string with all those chars I want to remove.

Let's say I have the following string in 1.txt file:

Mean concentrations **α**, maximum value ratio **β** and reductions in NO2 due to the lockdown **Δ**, March 2020, 2019 and 2018 in Madrid and Barcelona (Spain).

I want to remove `α`, `β`, and `Δ` chars from the string. This is my code as far.

```py
import glob 
import os 

chars_to_remove = '‘’“”|n.d.…•∈αβδΔεθϑφΣμτσχ€$∞http:www.←→≥≤<>▷×°±*⁃'

file_location = os.path.join('Desktop', 'Documents', '*.txt')
file_names = glob.glob(file_location)
print(file_names)

for f in file_names:
    outfile = open(f,'r',encoding='latin-1')
    data = outfile.read()
    if chars_to_remove in data:
        data.replace(chars_to_remove, '')
    outfile.close()
```

The variable `data` stores in each iteration all the content from the txt files. I want to check if there are `chars_to_remove` in the string and remove it with `replace()` function. I tried different approaches suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411771/best-way-to-replace-multiple-characters-in-a-string) and [here](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-remove-multiple-characters-from-a-string-in-python) without sucess.

Also, I tried to compare it as a list:

```
chars_to_remove = ['‘','’','“','”','|','n.d.','…','•','∈','α','β','δ','Δ','ε','θ','ϑ','φ','Σ','μ','τ','σ','χ','€','$','∞','http:','www.','←','→','≥','≤','<','>','▷','×','°','±','*','⁃']
```

but got datatype errors when comparing.

Any further idea will be appreciated!

Comment: Also, you're going to need to write `data` back into the file.

Comment: `for char in chars_to_remove: if char in data:...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be as fast, but why not use **Regex** to remove the characters/phrases?

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(‘|’|“|”|\||n.d.|…|•|∈|α|β|δ|Δ|ε|θ|ϑ|φ|Σ|μ|τ|σ|χ|€|$|∞|http:|www.|←|→|≥|≤|<|>|▷|×|°|±|\*|⁃)")
result = pattern.sub("", 'Mean concentrations α, maximum value ratio β and reductions in NO2 due to the lockdown Δ, March 2020, 2019 and 2018 in Madrid and Barcelona (Spain).')
print(result)
```

#### Output

```
Mean concentrations , maximum value ratio  and reductions in NO2 due to the lockdown , March 2020, 2019 and 2018 in Madrid and Barcelona (Spain).
```

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient way is *string.translate* in order to avoit loop on each invalid char.
Outfile must be define in some manner.

```
import glob 
import os
from string import maketrans

chars_to_remove = '‘’“”|n.d.…•∈αβδΔεθϑφΣμτσχ€$∞http:www.←→≥≤<>▷×°±*⁃'
translator = maketrans(chars_to_remove,'\0'*len(chars_to_remove))

file_location = os.path.join('Desktop', 'Documents', '*.txt')
file_names = glob.glob(file_location)
print(file_names)

for f in file_names:
    infile = open(f,'r',encoding='latin-1')
    data = infile.read()
    data.translate(translator).replace('\0','')
    infile.close()
    
    #Now data is translated
    # You must write it in a new file
    with open('...','wt') as outfile:
        outfile.write(data)
```

#### Hit

This code works, but it is inefficient, files  are fully loaded in memory.
a better way is to roll over infile and in the meanwhile write on outfile.