# Compare two string and replace letters

Tags: python

If I want to write a function `mask(a, b)` that takes two strings, `a` and `b`, and change the letters to `*` in `a` in the order they appear in `b`, returned in a new string.

For example if `s1="How are you doing today"` and `s2="hardod"` than the new string/updated s1 string should be `"*ow **e you **ing to*ay"`.

Is there any way to do this?

```
def mask(a,b):
    for ch in s2:
    
         s1 = s1.replace(ch, '*', 1)
    return s1

print(mask("How are you doing today", "hardod"))
```

Then I get the output `H*ll*, *ow **e you Anders?` which is wrong as they should be replaced in turn, ie the first letter in b should replace the same letter in a on the first index it appears on **and no more**, then b should continue to the second letter ib and replace the same letter ia on the first index on which it appears and no more etc.

Comment: hello, please show us your attempt. At leat, you can walk on a string with a for loop and compare each letter in s1 to s2 then it is the same , replace letter by '*'

Comment: here is a question that can help you- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411771/best-way-to-replace-multiple-characters-in-a-string

Comment: is it case sensitive?

Comment: @DonKnacki I have now posted my attempt, thank you!

Comment: @user15415514 : good. Two problems : you should not use s1 and s2 in your function but  a and b . About the first letter, as said by @vikash kumar, if you want to not take care about case, you can apply `lower()` to your sting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have done something like this :

```
def mask(a, b):
    start_index = 0
    for c in b:
        for i in range(start_index, len(a)):
            if c == a[i]:
                a = "".join((a[:i], "*", a[i+1:]))
                start_index = i+1
                break
    return a
```

Your choice to make it case sensitive or not.

Comment: And if I want to make in insensitive, where do I put `.lower()`? I tried with `if c.lower() == a[I].lower()` but with no success.

Comment: What you did works for me. But you could just set a and b to lowercase at the start of the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
def replace(s, position, character):
    return s[:position] + character + s[position+1:]

def mask(a,b):
    indexb=0
    for indexa in range(0,len(a)):
         ch=a[indexa]
         if (ch.lower()==b[indexb]):
            a=replace(a,indexa,'*')
            indexb=indexb+1
            if (indexb==len(b)):
                indexb=0
    return a

print(mask("How are you doing today", "hardod"))
```

gives

```
*ow **e you **ing to*ay
```