# merge two datasets based on a string match

Tags: python, pandas, string, merge, match

I have two datasets;

DF1 contains a column that has a short word.

DF2 has a column with a series of words, where in some cases they start with the short word from DF1

I would like to create a new column in DF2, and everytime the DF1 word appears at the beginning of DF2's word, to then place that DF1 word into the newly created column at that location.

The idea being that once completed, I can then merge the two datasets using the matching word.

How would I do this?

DF1

| ref |
| --- |
| ABC |
| DEF |
| GHI |

DF2

| word |
| --- |
| ABC123 |
| DEF456 |
| GHI789 |

DF2 - Desired output

| word | new column |
| --- | --- |
| ABC123 | ABC |
| DEF456 | DEF |
| GHI789 | GHI |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of pattern from `ref` column then try to extract it from `word` column:

```
import re

pattern = fr"({'|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in df1['ref'])})"
df2['new column'] = df2['word'].str.extract(pattern)
print(df2)

# Output
     word new column
0  ABC123        ABC
1  DEF456        DEF
2  GHI789        GHI
```

If it's too simple, you have to use `fuzzy` logic. You can check this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69125666/15239951) & [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69169135/15239951)

Comment: When trying on a larger data set, I'm getting a key error message on that 'new column' created, followed by another exception error message;

'ValueError: Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape'

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your data or a sample that raises this exception?

Comment: Ok. Can you update your post with a new row that can failed, please?

Comment: Managed to work it out. There were parenthesis in my pattern data, which was telling Regex to create new capture groups. Thanks :)

Comment: I updated my answer. Use `re.escape` to prevent this case. It should work now.

Comment: Sorry, and how would I go about doing the same match but where 'ref' appears at the start of 'word'? Imagine it would be using something along the lines of str.startswith?

Comment: If you want to match the start of the word, use: `pattern = fr"^({'|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in df1['ref'])})"` Note the *`^`*