# Thinking about the best way to merge two DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I'm looking for a way to merge df. However, I don't know what would be the best way to do this.

first df - metro cities/population/teams

| Metropolitan area | Population (2016 est.)[8] | NHL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Phoenix | 4661537 | Coyotes |
| Los Angeles | 13310447 | Kings Ducks |
| Toronto | 5928040 | Maple Leafs |
| Boston | 4794447 | Bruins |
| Edmonton | 1321426 | Oilers |
| New York City | 20153634 | Rangers Islanders Devils |

Second df - team/wins/losses

| team | w | L |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Los Angeles Kings | 46 | 28 |
| Phoenix Coyotes | 37 | 30 |
| Toronto Maple Leafs | 49 | 26 |
| Boston Bruins | 50 | 20 |
| Edmonton Oilers | 29 | 44 |
| New York Islanders | 34 | 37 |

I tried to merge across teams. However, I need to arrange this data so that it collides in the Merge. I don't know how I would do that without looking at it case by case.

Note: The data set is much larger and with more cities and teams.
I had a little trouble presenting the DF here, so I only put 6 rows and the main columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) from standard python library.

```
# Python >= 3.8 to use the walrus operator
import difflib

teams = df2['team'].tolist()

# Adjust cutoff parameter to avoid false positive
df1['team'] = [m[0] if (m := difflib.get_close_matches(area, teams, n=1, cutoff=0.3))
                    else None
                    for area in df1['Metropolitan area']]
```

Output

```
>>> df1
  Metropolitan area  Population (2016 est.)[8]                       NHL                 team
0           Phoenix                    4661537                   Coyotes      Phoenix Coyotes
1       Los Angeles                   13310447               Kings Ducks    Los Angeles Kings
2           Toronto                    5928040               Maple Leafs  Toronto Maple Leafs
3            Boston                    4794447                    Bruins        Boston Bruins
4          Edmonton                    1321426                    Oilers      Edmonton Oilers
5     New York City                   20153634  Rangers Islanders Devils   New York Islanders
```

Now you can merge your dataframe on `team` column. This code is very easily "parallelizable" with multiprocessing if your dataframe is very large.

You can also use [`thefuzz`](https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz) module to accomplish the same task. Take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/a/69169135/15239951

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the city part of a NHL team name, you could for example:

Make a hash map which contains all the possible city names; `{"Toronto": "Toronto"}`,

split the `NHL TEAM string` and check if the hash map contains any part of the string. If it does that's the city name.

With the limited amount of possible city names that's not too bad.

But I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish, you should elaborate and simplify your question.

Comment: Hello!
I apologize for not making my question so clear.
I tried to rewrite and put a clipping of the DF. However, I will try your suggestion as well. Thanks!