# Python3: Looping over a string

Tags: python

I would like to program something in python 3 and do not understand where my mistake is.

```
seq = ('1gnadutnpawihv\n  casc341')

check = ('0','1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')

while i < len(seq):
    for j in range(len(check)):
        if seq[i] == check[j]:
            seq=seq.replace(seq[i],"")
            

seq=seq.replace("\n","")
seq=seq.replace(" ","")

seq
```

I want to eliminate the characters `"\n"`, `" "`, and all numbers from `0 to 9` from the string seq with the replace function. Now I want to iterate over the seq and compare each character with each character of the tuple check and detect the numbers `0 to 9` and replace them afterwards with nothing.
The replacement method works for `"\n"` and `" "`, but not for the numbers.
The output is simply:

```
'1gnadutnpawihvcasc341'
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Your code is not a [mre] because `i` is not defined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to replace multiple characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411771/best-way-to-replace-multiple-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: You never define, nor update `i` so how does this even run? Anyway, why do you even need to iterate over `seq`? Just iterate over `check` and `replace` each one of them. [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) replaces ***all*** ocurrences anyway (just like you don't loop with `\n` and `' '`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the outer `while` loop. Instead of fixing it I removed it because it was redundant. I also removed the `\n` and spaces in the same loop:

```
seq = ('1gnadutnpawihv\n  casc341')
check = ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '\n', ' ')

for j in range(len(check)):
    seq = seq.replace(check[j], "")

print(seq)
```

Output:

```
gnadutnpawihvcasc
```

Comment: Or even `for char in check:`, then you don't need to index with `j`.

Comment: This is actually *not* how one should iterate over a string

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `while` or `if` statements. `while` is not necessary because `for` will terminate once it has iterated through the list given. `if` is not needed because `replace()` will have no affect if the passed substring is not present in the string. A `for` loop on its own is enough to produce he desired string.

---

Code:

```
seq = ('1gnadutnpawihv\n  casc341')

for x in list(range(10))+[" ", "\n"]:
    seq=seq.replace(f"{x}", "")
```

Output:

```
'gnadutnpawihvcasc'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to do what you're trying to do, but to answer your question

> Why doesn't it work?

the answer becomes clear if you look at `seq` after the error:

```
In [1]: seq = ('1gnadutnpawihv\n  casc341')
   ...: 
   ...: check = ('0','1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')
   ...: 
   ...: i = 0
   ...: while i < len(seq):
   ...:     for j in range(len(check)):
   ...:         if seq[i] == check[j]:
   ...:             seq=seq.replace(seq[i],"")
   ...: 
   ...:     i += 1
   ...: 
   ...: seq=seq.replace("\n","")
   ...: seq=seq.replace(" ","")
   ...: 
   ...: seq
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ef8657e9ddaa> in <module>
      6 while i < len(seq):
      7     for j in range(len(check)):
----> 8         if seq[i] == check[j]:
      9             seq=seq.replace(seq[i],"")
     10 

IndexError: string index out of range

In [2]: seq
Out[2]: 'gnadutnpawihv\n  casc'
```

`seq` went from 24 characters down to `20`.  Generally, changing the thing you're iterating over causes things like this to happen in Python.  I'm not actually sure how to get the output you posted, but I also had to make some changes (like define what `i` is) so I'm guessing your code has something else not shown.