# In Python, what is the fastest way to replace certain characters in a given string other than using str.translate()?

Tags: python, string

What is the fastest way to replace certain characters in a given string other than using `str.translate()`?

Given a `sequence` that only consists of letters "A", "T", "G", and "C", I want to replace each instance of "A" with "T", "T" with "A", "C" with "G", and "G" with "C". To do this, I used an ascii dictionary `map = {65:84,84:65,71:67,67:71}`, and do `sequence.translate(map)`. However, in `Python 3.8` this appears to be slow. I saw people mention using `byte` or `bytearray` to do this, but I just don't know how to make it work.

It looks like I first need to encode the sequence using `sequence.encode('ascii', 'ignore')` and then use `translate()` to do the translation?

Can anybody please help me?

For example,

```
sequence = 'ATGCGTGCGCGACTTT'
# {'A':'T', 'T':'A', 'C':'G', 'G':'C'}
map_dict = {65:84,84:65,71:67,67:71}
# expect 'TACGCACGCGCTGAAA'
sequence.translate(map_dict)
```

Comment: Do a favor, add some example code to make the view better of the case, adding the expected result.

Comment: It's not good practice to use python inbuilt function names for variables (`map`)

Comment: does your version of python not use ```"".replace("s","r")```

Comment: @MATOS Replace cannot work here, because X goes to Y and something else goes to X.

Comment: How does that limit anything replace just replaces every occurrence of that letter to one of your choice

Comment: OH I get what you are saying.

Comment: @MATOS Tim is right here, if you replace every A with T at the first place, in the second round, every T will be replaced to A, so it is not intended.

Comment: @DigitalFarmer Thanks, my code has been attached in the question.

Comment: Hi @sensationti I decided to delete my question and point you to this question which has generated a lot of responses and debates regarding timing for replacements → https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411771/best-way-to-replace-multiple-characters-in-a-string

Comment: Im away from my computer so i dont want write the tio to time it on mobile, but maybe something [like this](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyW5RMFWoVrdUd1KPURdRwFIWAE5QIYzkOEOYrgDGc7qtVzFqYWlqXnJqUD16o4h7s7uIOzs7ugcEhKizlVsq6Skl5WfmacRDTQzOjlWIS2/SCFZITNPAaYxVpOroCgzr0SjWPP/fwA)

Comment: Update, [nope](https://tio.run/##bZDNioMwFIX3PsXFjXGQokyrJeBCssgLZFfKkGpkMpjExuuilHl2J/0ROswEEs6Fc85H7njBT2ffl6X3zgBqozSCNqPz@JyiqFM9TEYP6kImdZ6VbVVKIwinaxFquCZNQhORZBAeGoYgWBD8JngQLPm@273C2VuI482X05YcQvzQHqF3HlrQFtb2Y/qEKjtJ1M6ifiHDvcvI8aPTD365o/tttt/ScpdVBS2rrKxoVfyCrvkNemmnQaIia0WgTXXcCM747TLeMCFE/FbkeRSNXlskj1WQQZpTJ@m6jDQDO5uT8nWw5nma/u9@/cWfyLL8AA)

Answer (score 0):

Assumption here is the sequence is very long, then this should be O(1):

If you maintain an index which contains the position of each letter in the sequence, then you just need to update the index to do bulk replacements.

For example given seq = "AGCTTCGA"

```
index = {"A": {0, 7}, "G": {1, 6}, "C": {2, 5}, "T": {3, 4}}
```

and if I understand correctly you want to do a swap:

```
def swap(index, charA, charB):
    tmp = index[charB]
    index[charB] = index[charA]
    index[charA] = tmp

swap(index, "A", "T")
print(index)
# {'A': {3, 4}, 'G': {1, 6}, 'C': {2, 5}, 'T': {0, 7}}
```

Comment: If the sequence is very long and the index is unknown, this won't work unless you create 4 lists to store the indices, right?

Comment: How would a complete implementation of this be O(1)? I'm pretty sure if you started from OP's input (a string) this would have to be at least O(n) to construct the dictionary then the two swaps then you'd have to reconstruct the string which would be at least another O(n)? Also you can just do `index[charB], index[charA] = index[charA], index[charB]`. Also wouldnt all that overhead would be less efficient than translate?

Comment: I read the problem statement as the swap being expensive, this swap is O(1), just a reference change. Yes you have to construct, but you have to construct any data structure, and this would not be expensive.  I was trying to offer a different approach that probably requires more information on how this structure is being used.