# Most elegant way to get rid of white space and new lines?

Tags: python, whitespace

I'm writing a script to parse specific data from each outlook email.

I wrote something to strip out all carriage returns, new space, and white spaces from my string before parsing it, but it's very ugly. Any ideas on making it more elegant?

```
messageStr = messageStr.replace("\r","")
messageStr = messageStr.split('\n')
messageStr = [i for i in messageStr if i != '']
messageStr = [i for i in messageStr if i != ' ']
```

Comment: You want to remove *all* whitespace? Or just leading and trailing whitespace? You want to do this for the whole message or on a line-by-line basis?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently carry out multiple string replacements in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367809/efficiently-carry-out-multiple-string-replacements-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

The `.strip` method of strings removes leading and trailing whitespace. If you wanted to get rid of the carriage returns on each line and other leading/trailing whitespace you could do this

```
lines = [line.strip() for line in message.split('\n')]
```

If you want to remove *all* whitespace, not just leading/trailing, you could do something similar against a string containing all whitespace you want to filter. The `string` module has a helper for this. The following would remove all whitespace from a string `s`:

```
import string
filtered_string = ''.join(char for char in s if char not in string.whitespace)
```

Answer (score 1):

This task is related to data cleaning task , Here is my approach :

Put all symbols in a list and then just check if any symbol is in list then delete it.

```
dummy_string='Hello this is \n example \r to remove '' the special symbols ' ''
special_sym=['\r','\n','',' ']


[dummy_string.split().__delitem__(j) for j,i in enumerate(dummy_string.split()) if i in special_sym]

print(" ".join(dummy_string.split()))
```

output:

```
Hello this is example to remove the special symbols
```

P.S : you don't need `'\r'`,`'\n'` in special_sym list because when you do `split()` it automatically removes those but still i showed there just for example.